# Use AWS API Gateway RestApi to get information about key

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am looking in to start using AWS API Gateway for my rest api.

I have been looking into their reference guide for the gateways internal rest api, link [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/)

I want to find information about a user from their key but my issue is that the rest api only seems to handle the key id, not the key value.

How can i get the key id from this rest api? Keep reading and testing queries in postman but i can't seem to  find a way to identify a user by their api key..

Does anyone else know how to do it?

Thought i was close with this query [`apikey:by-key`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/apikey-by-key/) but this is *by-keyId*

Answer (score 0):

You should not use API Gateway Keys to identify users. Their purpose is for usage plans and request limits. I suspect you want some sort of authentication system with users and if that's the case you need to implement AWS Cognito as the authorizer of the API Gateway (check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html)). From a Cognito pool you can extract information about your users.